# Set a variable in another package

Tags: perl

I'd like to set a variable with a chosen name in another package. How can I do this easily?

Something like:

```
$variable_name = 'x';
$package::$variable_name = '0';
# now $package::x should be == '0'
```

Comment: It is bad manners to tinker with another packages variables.  Perl allows it, but you're doing violence to the design of the other package.  Of course, there's a caveat: if the variable is exported by the package (not recommended, but certainly doable), then you may have permission to use it and you then don't have to do anything more than assign to it.

Comment: @Jonathan: I need to update some old code. Before, it did `require magic_config_file.pl;` (from absolute path) when it needed its configuration. I'm switching it to a module which can read proper local configuration files, but for backwards compatibility I need to set `%main::SOME_DB=(host=>'blah', user=>'blah'....`

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: a bigger caveat: if its documented that you may (e.g. Data::Dumper, Text::Wrap, etc.)

Comment: @ysth: of course - but if you're allowed to tinker with the variable, you don't have to go through contortions to use it.  Perl allows you to breach the protective walls placed around another package, but it often (but I am carefully not saying "always"!) is a bad idea to force your way into the internals of another package.

Comment: Packages aren’t really “protective walls”. They’re just for organizing things so that they don’t all live on the the same shelf on your bookshelves. Packages are for sharing, because they — and transitively, their contents — have well-known names that anybody can use.  In contrast, a scope is for not-sharing, because there are nameless. That said, it’s considered rather poor manners to play with unadvertised things, taking the attitude of, *“Gee, it wouldn’t be public if you weren’t to fiddle with it, right?”* That sort of thing is its own punishment in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that `$variable_name` was validated, you could do:

```
eval "\$package::$variable_name = '0'";
```

Comment: You really don't need to resort to an `eval STRING` just to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that, but you would have to disable strictures like so:

```
    package Test;

    package main;

    use strict;

    my $var_name = 'test';
    my $package = 'Test';

    no strict 'refs';
    ${"${package}::$var_name"} = 1;

print $Test::test;
```

So I'd not recommend that. Better to use a hash.

Answer (score 2):

```
use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;

{
    no warnings 'once';
    $A::B::C::D = 5; # a test subject
}

my $pkg = 'A::B::C';
my $var = 'D';

# tearing down the walls (no warranty for you):
    say eval '$'.$pkg."::$var"; # 5

# tearing down the walls but at least feeling bad about it:
    say ${eval '\$'.$pkg."::$var" or die $@}; # 5

# entering your house with a key (but still carrying a bomb):
    say ${eval "package $pkg; *$var" or die $@}; # 5

# using `Symbol`:    
    use Symbol 'qualify_to_ref'; 
    say $${ qualify_to_ref $pkg.'::'.$var }; # 5

# letting us know you plan mild shenanigans
# of all of the methods here, this one is best
{
    no strict 'refs';
    say ${$pkg.'::'.$var}; # 5
}
```

and if the following make sense to you, party on:

```
# with a recursive function:
    sub lookup {
        @_ == 2 or unshift @_, \%::;
        my ($head, $tail) = $_[1] =~ /^([^:]+:*)(.*)$/;
        length $tail
            ? lookup($_[0]{$head}, $tail)
            : $_[0]{$head}
    }
    say ${ lookup $pkg.'::'.$var }; # 5

# as a reduction of the symbol table:
    use List::Util 'reduce';
    our ($a, $b);

    say ${+ reduce {$$a{$b}} \%::, split /(?<=::)/ => $pkg.'::'.$var }; # 5
```

And of course you can assign to any of these methods instead of `say`ing them.

Comment: this doesn't work when you change the value in the package during run time, it can only get the init state